# How to use nagios monitor a windows process that have parameters?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I've already all environment working. I've used  the check_nt to monitor process, like this:

```
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               netserver
        contact_groups          admins, analysts
        service_description     DBAccess
        check_command           check_nt!PROCSTATE!-d SHOWALL -l dbaccess.exe
       }
```

This work. But now i need to monitor varios process that are the same .exe but have different parameters.

Like this:

appserver.exe -pf instance1.ini 
appserver.exe -pf instance2.ini 
appserver.exe -pf test.ini

How can i make it work? I can't figure how to use it with check_nt

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you haven't pointed out what do you want to monitor, I assume you want to check the process status. If the process is not running, NSClient++ will send notification to Nagios via NRPE.

Let's assume you are using NSClient++ for your windows monitoring with Nagios. 
First, you need to define appropriate alias under nsclient.ini in your windows machine (by default: C:\program files\NSClient++\nsclient.ini)

```
alias_check_appserver = check_process "process=appserver.exe -pf $ARG1$" "crit=state != 'started'"
```

Then you can define the service by simply changing the following line accordingly under your Nagios server:

For instance1:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               netserver
    contact_groups          admins, analysts
    service_description     DBAccess
    check_command           check_nrpe!alias_check_appserver -a "instance1.ini"
}
```

It should do the tricks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My nsclient.ini uses checkProcState like it:

alias_process = checkProcState "$ARG1$=started"

Is the same?

Comment: I would suggest you to use check_process as the checkProcState is a legacy version of check_process, you can have more detail: [NSClient Reference](https://docs.nsclient.org/reference/windows/CheckSystem.html)